# how do I change the position of date picker/ calendar icon in html and CSS without using bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I using and the calendar icon /date-picker is by default set on the right side(end of the input field). I want to move the calendar icon/date-picker at the beginning of the input field. I tried to change it but I can't get the proper property to change it. Please anyone can help to change it...! [i'm adding the picture which looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g8rB.png).here is the code which I used...

```
 <input class="input-field date" type="date" placeholder="Date and Time">
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    background: url(/*yourURLHere*/) no-repeat;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-width: thin
}
```

```html
<input class="input-field date" type="date" placeholder="Date and Time">
```

Comment: I want to change the date picker icon at the beginning of the input field. in which code you were added the position of date picker is the end of input field.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.input-field{
    height: calc(1.5em + 1rem + 2px);
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 2px solid black;

}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-width: thin
}
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
}
input::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;
}
input::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;
}
```

```html
 <input class="input-field date" type="date" placeholder="Date and Time">
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.

Comment: This won't work in Firefox

Answer (score -1):

It can be done as follow for input type date:

```
 //This is for the picker icon
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -20%;
}

// These for the input field container and date text
input::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: 5%;
}
input::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    position: relative;
    left: 5%;
}
```

```html
 <input class="input-field date" type="date" placeholder="Current Date">
```

If you would also like to change the icon then, you can choose the icon from here https://materialdesignicons.com/ and then also change it in code as follow:

```
// I change the icon to clock-outline, which I selected from https://materialdesignicons.com/

input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    background: 'mdi mdi-24px mdi-clock-outline' no-repeat;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -20%;
}
```