# change clock symbol order in input type=time

Tags: css, css-selectors

The type=time input has a clock symbol on the right but I would like to put it on the left, does anyone know how?

thank you so much

Just as I have increased the size I would like to put the clock on the left.

`input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { font-size: 20px; }`

[image: My input]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I change the position of date picker/ calendar icon in html and CSS without using bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70602544/how-do-i-change-the-position-of-date-picker-calendar-icon-in-html-and-css-witho)

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned it, there is this solution which apply well to `input[type="time"]`:

[Change the position of date-picker/calendar icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70602544/how-do-i-change-the-position-of-date-picker-calendar-icon-in-html-and-css-witho)

Another solution would be to hide the clock icon and the empty space with:

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { 
    background: none; 
    display: none; 
}
```

and adding an icon on the right by yourself.